# Spring: Can single class have multiple @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a two simple questions:

1. Is there a functionality to have more than one @Transactional method in single bean? If I use them in another bean and execute them one by one, will they work in proper way?

```
class A {
 @Transactional
 public void actionA() {}

 @Trancational
 public void actionB() {}
}

class B {

 private A a;

 void doSomeStuff() {
   a.actionA();
   a.actionB();
 }
}
```

2. Does bean class has to be public if contains @Transactional? I know that methods must be public but whole class too?

Sorry, if another thread exists, but I could not find

Comment: have you tried implementing it like this?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly fine.  When bean B calls a method of bean A (which is wrapped in the transactional proxy) you pass the proxy boundary and it will start and commit/rollback a transaction. You might want to read up on proxies when starting with Spring as most of the 'magic' is merely proxy stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes its possible, you can have two @Transactional methods in a single class and they work as you expect. However it is important to notice that your doSomeStuff() is not transactional even though it invokes two transactional methods because even if the actionB() fails it has no impact on actionA() because the transaction is already committed.
2. It has nothing to do with transactional methods.